# Ensuring template type consistency at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have this template class:

```
template <class Tin, class Tout>
class Foo
{
    Tin input;
    Tout output;

    static inline void __ensure_type_consistency
    {
        int16_t* p = (int16_t *)0;
        // uint16_t* p1 = p;
        Tin* check_type_in = p;
        Tout* check_type_out = p;  
    }
public:
    ...
}
```

I want to make sure that `Tin` and `Tout` are both typedef'd to type `int16_t` and not some other type. (**NOTE:** *please read the full question before jumping to conclusions*)

If I uncomment the commented line, I get an error as expected; the compiler doesn't allow pointers of different types to be assigned to each other without a cast:

```
"src\foo.h", line 47: error #145: a value of type "int16_t *" 
cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "uint16_t *"
```

But if I keep it commented out, and I instantiate:

```
Foo<uint16_t, int32_t> illegalFoo;
```

I don't get compiler errors, even though the same type of check is used (creating an incompatible pointer assignment in a static function that is never actually called, but which should cause compiler errors)

**Is there a way to create a static compile-time type consistency check?** Why doesn't the one I'm using work?

**NOTE**: Ignore for a moment the obvious solution of just getting rid of the template parameters. That would "solve" this problem, but there are some out-of-band things going on here with my debugging tools where typedefs are being used to impart important metadata: I want to ensure that `Foo.input` is of type `Tin` where `Tin` is either an `int16_t` or a typedef that resolves as an `int16_t`, and similarly with `Foo.output` and `Tout`. There are slight differences from the perspective of my debugging tools, where typedef'd types and their base type can be distinguished, even though within a C++ program they are identical.

---

**edit:** by the way, this is an embedded system, and I can't use Boost. It's also not C++0x.

Comment: Gah! Double underscore names == reserved for the compiler...

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are passing a `uint16_t` as argument to your template, not a `int16_t`. What is the exact consistency check that you want to perform? Do you want to allow both `uint16_t` and `int16_t`? Is that a typo (there are others in the presented code)?

Comment: Why can't you use Boost on an embedded system anyway? I'm using it on a embedded medical system at the moment.

Comment: @dribeas: I want to allow `int16_t` as a template parameter but not `uint16_t`, or `int32_t` or any other type but one identical to `int16_t`. Typos? Where?

Comment: @GrahamS: This is a TI C28xxx DSP. There are embedded systems and then there are embedded systems. The more capable ones usually have megabytes of RAM and are capable of running an OS (e.g. embedded Linux or smartphones). I work w/ less capable ones which have < 32K of RAM, and sometimes have weird memory setups. As far as I know, Boost has not been ported to my system, and even if it were, I'm not sure the costs (compile speed, mainly) would be tolerable for this one check.

Comment: Foo<uint16_t, int32_t> just gives substitution failure on \__ensure_type_consistency(), so it isn't instantiated. On Foo<int16_t, int16_t> there's no substitution failure, so it's compiled and you then get the compiler error on "uint16_t* p1 = p;"

Comment: Tonttu: could you post this as an answer and elaborate a little? This looks like the correct answer.

Comment: @Jason S: Fair enough. We ported Boost ourselves to use on the current system (LynxOS based) as we needed it for the project. I've done my share of "real" embedded systems on <32k TI MSP430 chips myself, but we've always just used straight C for those!

Comment: @GrahamS: "We ported Boost ourselves" (wow!!!) I always use C++ if I can help it. There are so many useful features that enable modularity & don't have runtime resource costs. TI's C++ compiler (which btw works nicely on MSP430) is fairly efficient, even on templates. I wouldn't touch dynamic memory allocation w/ a 10' pole, and virtual functions have their slight cost, but most other C++ features work well w/o any overhead, especially if you inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way:

```
template <class, class> class Foo;

template <>
class Foo<int16_t, int16_t> {
  ...
};
```

The other way, if your conditions are actually more complicated, is to use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` from Boost or `static_assert` from C++0x.  Since you wanted non-Boost options and C++0x may not work, here's something more similar to what you posted in your example:

```
(void)(true ? (int16_t**)0 : (Tin**)0);
```

and the same for `Tout`.  That needs to be in some method that is either called or has its address taken (the idiom for doing that is at the end of [the Boost.Concept_check implementation documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/concept_check/implementation.htm)).  If you want something like the `is_same`/`static_assert` solution others have posted but without Boost or C++0x, try:

```
template <class, class> struct types_valid {static const int value = -1;};
template <> struct types_valid<int16_t, int16_t> {static const int value = 1;};
```

Then put `static char foo[types_valid<Tin, Tout>::value];` in your class outside of any methods.  I believe you won't need to actually define `foo` as long as you don't refer to it anywhere.

Comment: No, that won't work. I need the member variables to be of type Tin and Tout, not int16_t. (again, they're identical from the perspective of C++, but not from my debug tools)

Comment: @Jason S: Try the last thing I posted more recently (using `?:`), and see if that satisfies your requirements.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. I wonder if the template types are causing the compiler to overlook its normal type checking.

Comment: Are you putting that code in your method and then trying to call the method?  If you don't call the method, the type checks inside it won't run.

Comment: Ah -- perhaps that's it. I don't actually want to run the code if I don't have to, but it would be OK (if not quite as nice) if they only ran once during the constructor.

Comment: The code should be optimized out, but I just added another variant into my answer for you to try.

Comment: Aha! That does it. If I call `__ensureTypeConsistency()` in the constructor, it works. Why is the compile-time check more rigorous for non-template pointer types? I don't have to actually run `__ensureTypeConsistency()` to get that uint16_t* line to fail.

Comment: You have to have the check in some method that actually gets called (or has its address taken) for it to be instantiated.

Comment: Cool! "has its address taken" seems to do the trick as well; I just have a statement `__ensureTypeConsistency;` without the actual function call, and that does it.

Comment: Accepted this answer because of your comment that mentions the trick of taking the address of a function w/o actually calling it. (suggest you revise your answer to include that)

Comment: I did that update, plus a link to how the Boost Concept Checking Library makes sure its checks are instantiated.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `is_same` type trait in a `static_assert`.  The C++0x would look like:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<Tin, std::int16_t>::value &&
              std::is_same<Tout, std::int16_t>::value, "o noez");
```

You can find both [the `is_same` type trait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) and the [static assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) in Boost as well.  Even if you are compiling for an embedded system, it is straightforward to extract just the type traits and static assert headers from Boost and neither of those libraries have any runtime overhead.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use boost or C++1x, you can make your own `is_same` compile-time type comparator and hack up some poor-man's compile-time assertion

```
// Beware, brain-compiled code ahead!
template< typename T1, typename T2>
struct is_same      { static const bool result = false; };

template< typename T > 
struct is_same<T,T> { static const bool result = true; };

template< bool Condition, typename Dummy = void >
struct static_assert {
  typedef bool result;
};

template<typename IntentionalError>
struct static_assert<false,IntentionalError> {
  typedef typename IntentionalError::does_not_exist result;
};
```

and use it like this:

```
template <class Tin, class Tout>
class Foo
{
    Tin input;
    Tout output;

    typedef typename static_assert<is_same<Tin ,int16_t>::result>::result Tin_test;
    typedef typename static_assert<is_same<Tout,int16_t>::result>::result Tout_test;
    typedef typename static_assert<is_same<Tout,Tout   >::result>::result Tout_test;
// ...
};
```

Comment: Arf, beat me to it :p @Jason: types are necessarily checked by the compiler while methods are only checked if they are used.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, how is that a compile-time test? If the test fails I want to cause a compile-time error.

Comment: @Jason: It might not work (I haven't compiled it), but the way it was intended to work the `static_assert<false,..>` specialization will fail to compile if `IntentionalError` is (the default parameter) `void`, since `void` doesn't have a nested `does_not_exist` type.

Answer (score 2):

Your method works, but you must actually call __ensure_type_consistency ( ) somewhere for the compiler to throw the error. If the method is never called, then the compiler thinks it can ignor it.

I just tried it in VC++ 2010, and it works.

---

Are you using GCC? Try putting using **attribute** ((used)) on __ensure_type_consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Boost Concept Checks:

```
BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::Integer<Tin>));
BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::Integer<Tout>));
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/concept_check/using_concept_check.htm

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted several responses to this question, and this seems to do the trick nicely:

A helper class:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct TypeConsistency
{
private:
    static inline void checkfunction()
    {
        T1* p1 = (T1 *)0;
        T2* p2 = p1;
    }
public:
    static inline void check() { checkfunction; }
    /* The above line does nothing at runtime,
     * but takes the address of checkfunction(),
     * which causes a compile-time type check.
     */ 
};
```

Applying this in my foo class:

```
template <class Tin, class Tout> 
class Foo
{
    Tin input;
    Tout output;

public:
    Foo() { 
        TypeConsistency<int16_t, Tin>::check();
        TypeConsistency<int16_t, Tout>::check();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I misread the question, but now that I have reread it, I think you will be better off with some type of static assert that does not require creating functions: `template <class A,class B> struct is_same { static const bool value = false; }; template <class A> struct is_same<A,A> { static const bool value = true; }; typedef char assert_are_same[ is_same<T1,uint16_t>::value? 1 : -1 ];` or something in that line does not require the compiler to generate code at all.

Comment: Note that typedefs are only aliases but they represent a single type. That means that `typedef int a; typedef int b; is_same<a,b>::value;` will evaluate to true.

Comment: @dribeas: interesting... so the `typedef char somedummyexpr[-1];` is what would cause the compile failure?